# calculate sum of sal based on two tables

Tags: postgresql

Two tables like

table1

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | sname | sal |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | X     | 100 |
|  2 | Y     | 200 |
|  3 | Z     | 400 |
+----+-------+-----+
```

Table2

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | sname | sal |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | A     | 500 |
|  2 | B     | 200 |
|  3 | C     | 400
|  4   A       100
+----+-------+-----+
```

Both the tables having relation ship id column

i need calculate the sum sal group by table1.sname at the same time those who are matched to table2

the output like

```
+-------+-------+---------------------
| Table1.sname | Table2.sname   | sum |
+-------+-------+-----+ ----------------
| A         | W         | 600 |
| B         | Y         | 200 |
| B         | F         | 300 |
| C         | Z         | 400 |
+-------+-------+----------------------



select sum(sal),a.sname,b.sname 
from table1 a,
     (select id,sname from table2 group by sname,id) as b 
where a.id=b.id 
group by a.sname,b.sname;
```

but its not given proper o/p

Comment: Where is your SQL code?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Provide more examples of input data with expected result or more detailed description of what should be done

Answer (score 1):

your question is little ambiguous...but maybe you want this.

query

```
select Table11.id, Table1.sname, Table2.sname, (Table1.sal+Table2.sal) as Sum
from Table1, Table2
where Table1.id = Table2.id;
```

result

```
 Table1.id | Table2.sname | Table2.sname | sum
-----------+--------------+--------------+-----
         1 | a            | d            | 500
         2 | b            | e            | 700
         3 | c            | f            | 900
```

Comment: This is not am expecting